# symfony token jwt with gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token for api

Tags: api, symfony, jwt, refresh-token

We have implemented a refresh token system with the bundle "gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token" which was working but not optimized when changing the token info. So I decided to set up a new token when changing the user profile and not wait until the end of the token validity.

At the level of the back, I remove the last refresh token set up, and I send back to the front a new token with its refresh token which is stored in database.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

[image: img1]

But unfortunately, when the token refreshes, I get a 401 error with the following message.

[image: img2]

I don't think it's the same solution, but I don't see any other